# Query Firebase Data From Different Nodes

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have the following data structure.

[image]

And I want to do pagination/infinite scroll on this data by doing QueryOrderedByValue. The problem is I don't know how to query the data from two different branches at once. I know how to do with just one branch but not sure how to do it with two branches.

The current method I am doing now is running this through each branch:

```
metadataRef.queryOrderedByValue().queryEnding(atValue: highest).queryLimited(toLast: UInt(limit))
```

This is problematic because the data is no longer in order, and the array is likely reordered each time the data is pulled. If anyone has a solution for this, I'd be very grateful! Also, I am doing this in Swift, so swift code would be helpful too.

EDIT: The only other solution I can think of for this is to download all the data at once and then order them. But I worry this might be an issue when there's hundreds of thousands of entries.

Comment: How about you maintain your local collection and sort it as per needed once you pull data from Firebase?

Comment: Do you mean pulling all the data at once and then cache it?

Comment: Not necessarily. You want pagination and you'd be pulling data multiple times. Once each query returns filtered data, append it in your local collection and sort it for the sake of newly appended data.

Comment: That's what I am currently doing, but because I am displaying data at the same time. So each time I resort it the table would change instead of just appending data to the end.

Comment: Minor confusion here. So you want to fetch from 2 nodes, sorted and filtered in such a way that it should append to the end in table?

Comment: Yes, that is what I want to do. And in a way such that I dont have to pull all the data at once

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured that I need a news feed node for each user. This is a good read if you are running into the same problem.

https://firebase.googleblog.com/2015/10/client-side-fan-out-for-data-consistency_73.html